# Method ViewDidLoad not called from sub-class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

In my iPhone App.

I have two view controllers.

They have SuperClass-SubClass Relation.(Inheritance).

Let Say ViewController1 is a SuperClass and ViewController2 is a SubClass.

They both share a common nib file of super class.

So, Ideally all the methods of ViewController1 is inherited to ViewController2 (If I am not overriding it in ViewController2).

So, To check this When I am

My viewcontroller2 Loads viewDidLoad not called from super class.

```
**ViewController1

-ViewDidLoad

-ViewWillApper


**ViewController2

Other methods but I am not writing ViewDidLoad and ViewWillAppear
//---------------
```

So,When this separate page ViewController2 is called.
ViewDidLoad is not called of SuperClass.
But ViewWillAppear is called.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that `-viewDidLoad:` is only called once because the same nib file is shared between the two classes.  After the first time the nib is loaded into memory, `-viewDidLoad:` is called.  It isn't called a second time because it's simply being reused from memory where it already resides, so it does not need to be reloaded.  This would explain why `-viewWillAppear:` is still called.

[UIViewController Class Reference: -viewDidLoad:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW25)

> **viewDidLoad**
>
> Called after the controller’s view is loaded into memory.
>
> - (void)viewDidLoad
>
> **Discussion**
>
> This method is called after the view controller has loaded its associated views into memory. This method is called
>   regardless of whether the views were stored in a nib file or created
>   programmatically in the loadView method. This method is most commonly
>   used to perform additional initialization steps on views that are
>   loaded from nib files.

Answer (score 0):

How can you say that your `ViewController1` and `ViewController2` are having Inheritance?? Post the code of `ViewController2.h` file.

Are you doing like

```
@interface ViewController2 : ViewController1 {
}
```

if you are doing like above then only you can say that you are inheriting the VC2 from VC1. And only then you will be able to call `viewDidLoad` of VC1.

If you are using only 1 xib files and 2 VC and the case you discuss does not mean that you are inheriting.

when you write

```
ViewController1 *vc1 = [[ViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController1"];
```

and

```
ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController1"];
```

this means that you reuse your .xib file and does not inherits the class...